# C++ stdex::wregex issue with \S\s

Tags: c++, regex

I have been trying to parse some wstrings using std::wregex and have found that when I use [\S\s]+ it fails to handle the Unicode character EN-DASH (8211).

Does anyone know if there is a reason that EN-DASH is not seen as either white space or none white space, or am I doing something wrong?

```
void test (const std::wstring& testDesc, const std::wstring& expresion, const std::wstring& text)
{
    std::wcout << L"Test   : " << testDesc << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Regex  : " << expresion << std::endl;
    std::wregex regex (expresion);
    std::wstring regExParams (text);
    if (std::regex_search (regExParams, regex))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Result : Matched" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Result : No match" << std::endl;
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    const std::wstring text1 = L"¬Line1\nLine2¬Line3\nLine4¬Line–5¬";       // 3rd char from the end is the EN-DASH
    const std::wstring text2 = L"¬Line1\nLine2¬Line3\nLine4¬Line-5¬";       // 3rd char from the end if a hyphen
    const std::wstring expresion1 = L"^¬[\\S\\s]+¬[\\S\\s]+¬[\\S\\s]+¬$";   // This pattern will fail on EN-DASH
    const std::wstring expresion2 = L"^¬[^¬]+¬[^¬]+¬[^¬]+¬$";               // This pattern will succeeds with EN-DASH
    test (L"Test 1", expresion1, text1);    // Fail
    test (L"Test 2", expresion2, text1);    // Pass
    test (L"Test 3", expresion1, text2);    // Pass
    test (L"Test 4", expresion2, text2);    // Pass
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  How are you compiling the code?

Comment: Work as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8014ddaae00fe499).

Comment: All 4 tests matched on my machine.

Comment: Please note that code above do not contain problematic character. Something get broken with encoding during code paste: `▌` is something different then `¬` https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: @MarekR I think that reference might be broken.  An en dash is `–`, not `▌` ( the OP has one in `Line–5`).  Looks like part of the reference is right, as it has the right image and some of the right information, but the windows code is definitely wrong.

Comment: This is result of `Alt-2013` on windows as link suggests and it got broken too.

Comment: Yes sorry, the code was sanitised as I pasted it in.  text1 should contain an EN-DASH towards the end.  The ¬ character is not a problem (AFAIK) its just a separator because I can't use a comma.  
I am using Visual Studio 2019, v16.1.2  
And thanks everyone for looking at it.